# SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, migration

I've recently installed SSMA and after connecting to both the Oracle instance (which holds the database to be converted) and the SQL Server I've mapped the necessary schemas from Oracle to MSSQL.  The problem is that when I click on the report button for the assessment report there's an error popping up:

> Assesment Error : Nothing to Process

The output window states:

> Starting conversion... Analyzing metadata... Conversion finished with
>   0 errors, 0 warnings, and 0 informational messages. There is nothing
>   to process.

Does anyone who has experience with SSMA have any idea about this error? I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use SQL Profiler (there should be such tools for Oracle too, we used Toad for Oracle) and see what queries SSMA executes to Oracle and MS SQL databases and what exceptions happen there ...

There are number of reasons why a tool can fail - in the past we used 3rd party migration tool that could fail if databases have different encodings (collations) especially when master SQL database was made CASE sensitive ... Though, I have no experience with SSMA, I would suggest that SQL profiling could give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a last resort, i'll use SQL Profiler to see what exactly is SSMA executing.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here.... what user are you logging into Oracle with? Sounds a bit like there could be some permissions issues.

You are trying to convert to SS 2005, right?

Comment: system - isn't this user the equivalent of "sa" on SQL ?

Comment: system should work. told you it was just a guess ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize your SqlServer Db (to persist new schema etc). Right click on your db in "Sql Server Metadata Explorer", from context menu click synchronize with database. 
Tool has a convention that requires same db name on your actual sql server. This is the situation in version 4.2. I hope it helps.